# SciPy ODR "Ordinary" Least Squares?

Tags: scipy, least-squares, statistics, regression

Scipy.odr has a setting for "fit types", [including one for ordinary least-squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.ODR.set_job.html#scipy.odr.ODR.set_job). This matches with the [documentation of ODRPACK](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odrpack_guide.pdf) (see p. 31, Computational method).

However, the package accepts standard deviations/weights in this mode and the weights do affect the fit result:

```
In [1]: from scipy import odr
   ...: def f(B, x):
   ...:     return B[0]*x + B[1]
   ...: lin = odr.Model(f)
   ...: mydata = odr.RealData([0, 1, 2], [1,1,2], sy=[0.01,1,1])
   ...: myodr = odr.ODR(mydata, lin, beta0=[0,1])
   ...: myodr.set_job(fit_type=2)
   ...: myoutput = myodr.run()
   ...: print(myoutput.beta)
   ...: print(myoutput.sd_beta)
[0.400012 0.99998 ]
[0.200016   0.00447205]

In [2]: mydata = odr.RealData([0, 1, 2], [1,1,2], sy=[0.5,1,1])
   ...: myodr = odr.ODR(mydata, lin, beta0=[0,1])
   ...: myodr.set_job(fit_type=2)
   ...: myoutput = myodr.run()
   ...: print(myoutput.beta)
   ...: print(myoutput.sd_beta)
[0.42857143 0.95238096]
[0.23328473 0.21295886]
```

My question is: Is this really an **ordinary** least-squares fit, or rather a **weighted** least-squares fit? The documentation states one thing clearly, the behaviour shows the other.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [ODRPACK Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odrpack_guide.pdf) it seems clear that by "ordinary least squares", the authors mean least squares in which the errors are (considered to be) only in the dependent variables, and not also in the independent variables. The "ordinary least squares" option does indeed use weights. In fact, contrary to popular usage, not only does the package's "ordinary least squares" option use weights, but it may also be nonlinear (least squares), as opposed to linear least squares. So ODRPACK's "ordinary" least squares is not that ordinary.

Don't blame me, I'm only the messenger. I didn't write the package or choose its nomenclature.

Comment: Thank you, I am not blaming you at all, I rather feel reassured that it is in fact not "ordninary", but non-linear and actually weighted. :)